# Swift async cancel like URLSession

Tags: swift, asynchronous, nsurlsessiondatatask

when i use callback function with URLSession, i can use URLSessionDataTask to cancel a task

```swift
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!)) { data, response, error in
    // handle response
}
task.cancel()
```

when i use async func with URLSession, there is not any cancel method for it, how to cancel it before it completed

```
try await URLSession.shared.datafrom(from: URL(string: "")!)
```

i cannot found cancel method for async func for URLSession, i can check task cancel after task complete like this

```swift
try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: ""))
try Task.checkCancellation()
```

how to cancel URLSessionTask before it completed

Comment: Surely you do not want to cancel it immediately? At some point in your code you would create a `Task { ... }` that involves calling whatever `async` method this code is in, right? You can cancel that `Task` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel the whole operation

```swift
let task = Task {
    try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: ""))
}
task.cancel()
```

**URLSessionDataTask** should be canceled at the moment

Comment: “… be canceled at the moment”, is this really correct? Won’t the `Task` be cancelled once `data(from:)` has completed? I find the documentation for this really unclear.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tested in swift playground. It cancels as expected

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should investigate this a bit more myself.